# VBA Macro to AutoFill multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba

I currently use this code to autofill formulas to the last filled column:

```
Dim lngLastColumn As Long

lngLastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

Range(Activecell, Cells(Activecell.Row, lngLastColumn)).FillRight
```

But it only works for one row at a time. Is there a way to apply it to all the rows I've selected?

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try this:

```
Dim lngLastColumn As Long
lngLastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Selection.Columns(1).Cells
    Range(cell, Cells(cell.Row, lngLastColumn)).FillRight
Next
```